# how to find the higher value between the previous value in a column

Tags: r

how to find the higher value by the previous value in a column:

```r
df=tibble(value=c(NA,20,21,10,30,20,22))
```

Expected output:

```
NA,21,21,30,30,22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pmax` to get maximum between current and previous value.

```
library(dplyr)  
df %>% mutate(higher = pmax(value, lag(value), na.rm = TRUE))

#  value higher
#  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1    NA     NA
#2    20     20
#3    21     21
#4    10     21
#5    30     30
#6    20     30
#7    22     22
```

This can also be written in base R as :

```
df$higher <- pmax(df$value, c(NA, df$value[-nrow(df)]), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

If you don't want the result to be a new column and to get output similar to what you have shown you can use :

```
pmax(df$value[-1], df$value[-nrow(df)])
#[1] NA 21 21 30 30 22
```